# Drop rows with zero time in org-mode agenda clockreport

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I recently found `org-agenda-clockreport`. Because I keep all my `.org` files in a single directory (indexed by `deft`), including files with notes and no tasks, I get a table with tens of rows, with only one or two that have any time logged. Is there any way to drop any rows in the clockreport that have zero time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer by searching for variables with "agenda" and "clock" and "report" using Helm.

The variable `org-agenda-clockreport-parameter-plist` can be modified with the following
key/value pairs:

```
:stepskip0 t
:fileskip0 t
```

I modified the variable using Emacs' customize screen, but then I moved it from
custom.el to my own init.el, and this works for me:

```
(setq org-agenda-clockreport-parameter-plist '(:stepskip0 t :link t :maxlevel 2 :fileskip0 t))
```

The other two keys (`:link` and `:maxlevel`) were already set in `org-agenda-clockreport-parameter-plist`.  You may wish to modify only the keys `:setpskip0` and `:fileskip0`
but I don't know how to do that in Emacs lisp (yet) :)

If you have clock reports *outside* of the agenda, the same parameters work.  For example:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope agenda :maxlevel 3 :block today :stepskip0 t :fileskip0 t :link t
#+END
```

Press Ctrl-C Ctrl-C on the above code block to get a clock report outside of the agenda.

See section 8.4.2 "The Clock Table" in Org-mode's info section:
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/The-clock-table.html

```
:stepskip0’
     When non-‘nil’, do not show steps that have zero time.

:fileskip0’
     When non-‘nil’, do not show table sections from files which did not
     contribute.
```

Thanks,
--Nate