# How can I format the orgmode clocktable in the agenda view?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-clock-table

In the org-mode Agenda view, I can add a clocktable by pressing `R`.  However, in this table I would like to hide non-contributing files.  In any other dynamic clocktable block, I would specify `:fileskip0`.  How can I achieve this for the clocktable in the Agenda view?  I would like this formatting by default, i.e. it should show up after just pressing `R`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, I should have dug a little deeper...

The solution is in the variable `org-clocktable-defaults`.  I set it using

`(setq org-clocktable-defaults '(:maxlevel 2 :lang "en" :scope file :block nil :wstart 1 :mstart 1 :tstart nil :tend nil :step nil :stepskip0 nil :fileskip0 t :tags nil :match nil :emphasize nil :link nil :narrow 40! :indent t :formula nil :timestamp nil :level nil :tcolumns nil :formatter nil))`

which is all default values, except for `:fileskip0`, which I changed from `nil` to `t`.

Comment: See also https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/52048/drop-rows-with-zero-time-in-org-mode-agenda-clockreport